# How to mark blocked a ticket in a Service Desk project in JIRA?

Tags: jira

I did not find any "Flag" or "Mark Blocked" button when editing a JIRA ticket in a Service Desk project. Someone know wether it is possible or not?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by blocking a ticket?

Comment: Filter out how many ticket assigned to me is really open and not blocked by someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know how many tickets assigned to you are blocked by someone the best way to do this is to have a status in the workflow that reflects this. For example a status like "Blocked". Then you can use a JQL function to know how many issues assigned to you are in this status

```
assignee = currentUser() and status = Blocked
```

If you are not an Admin, ask the admin to add this status for you. Please take into account that the [default Jira Service Desk workflow has statuses that might work for you](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/default-service-desk-project-configuration-776636295.html#Defaultservicedeskprojectconfiguration-Workflows).